# A sample of size n = 20 is drawn from a population with population proportion, p = 0.40. Find the mean

Tags: probability

A sample of size $ n = 20 $ is drawn from a population with population proportion $ p = 0.40 $. Assume that the sample size is less than or equal to $ 5 \% $ of the population. Let $ \hat{P} $ be the sample proportion.

**Question:** Find the mean.

I have no clue how to find the mean in this case.

Comment: is this binomial distribution?check it if    is  helpful  http://classweb.gmu.edu/tkeller/HANDOUTS/Handout10.pdf

Comment: also this http://www.statisticslectures.com/topics/samplesizepopulationproportion/

Comment: @OP Please ***do not*** deface your post like this.

Comment: @Joe: I have rolled back your question. Do not deface your post especially when someone has invested time in your question and answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ X $ be the number of successes recorded in the sample, which can be viewed as a collection of $ 20 $ Bernoulli trials. Then $ X \sim \text{Binom}(20,0.4) $.

The sample proportion, by definition, is $ \hat{P} = \dfrac{X}{20} $; its mean (expectation) is calculated as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{E}[\hat{P}] &= \text{E} \left[ \frac{X}{20} \right] \\
                  &= \frac{1}{20} \cdot \text{E}[X] \\
                  &= \frac{1}{20} \cdot (20)(0.4) \\
                  &= 0.4.
\end{align}

If you increase the sample size $ n $, then by the Central Limit Theorem, the probability distribution of $ \hat{P} $ is approximately $ \text{N} \left( p,\dfrac{p(1 - p)}{n} \right) $.

Comment: do we need to know that sample size is  less by $5$% from population size?

Comment: Usually, one applies the Central Limit Theorem to a very large sample. However, we only have $ n = 20 $ in this case.

Comment: generally we can't directly  calculate  population proportion from sample size and  sample proportion right?

Comment: Yes, that’s true. However, if the sample size is large, then we can construct confidence intervals for $ p $ using the Central Limit Theorem. This is basically what you have shown. :)

Comment: However, the OP has already specified $ p $ as $ 0.4 $, so I don’t think that is what he’s trying to do.